# How to copy/export required GA4 events from one property to another

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have created one GA4 property (property-1) and one of our partner/vendor team creating another GA4 property (property-2).  When we launch our vendor pages the events are getting tracked through Property-2.

Is there any way that to copy few/specific events from Property-2 to Property-1 without manual way.
We are thinking like manually exporting the property-2 events to CSV from bigquery linking. Then import the events csv into Property-1, which seems manual process and not a feasible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use The [google analytics data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) to extract from each property.

```
POST https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/GA4_PROPERTY_ID:runReport
  {
    "dateRanges": [{ "startDate": "2020-09-01", "endDate": "2020-09-15" }],
    "dimensions": [{ "name": "country" }],
    "metrics": [{ "name": "activeUsers" }]
  }
```

This data is extracted in Json format so you will need to format it however you want in order to do your analytics.

```
{
  "dimensionHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "country"
    }
  ],
  "metricHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "activeUsers",
      "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "dimensionValues": [
        {
          "value": "Japan"
        }
      ],
      "metricValues": [
        {
          "value": "2541"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": [
        {
          "value": "France"
        }
      ],
      "metricValues": [
        {
          "value": "12"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {},
  "rowCount": 2
}
```

Note: At the time of writing the Google analytics data api is still in Beta.  And may change in the future.

> This is a Beta version of the product. While no breaking changes are expected in this phase, pre-GA products may have limited support, and changes to pre-GA products may not be compatible with other pre-GA versions.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply, is https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1 working for data import from another GA4 property tag